Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> $formData ]] in class App\Livewire\FloatingChat
i made FloatingChat  for my chat app with laravel and livewire 3 controller and blade, when i press submit button it will be store all value from input form to local and database mySql also and it send to my controller for check is value of conversation is exist or not
this my javascript for submit
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const reasonInput = document.getElementById('reason-input');
        const submitFormBtn = document.getElementById('submit-form');
        const userForm = document.getElementById('user-form');

        submitFormBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
            const phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
            const selectedUserId = reasonInput.value;

            if (name && email && phone && selectedUserId) {
                // Save form data to local storage
                const formData = {
                    name,
                    email,
                    phone
                };
                localStorage.setItem('chatFormData', JSON.stringify(formData));

                // Emit formDataSubmitted event to Livewire
                Livewire.dispatch('formDataSubmitted', formData, selectedUserId);
                console.log(selectedUserId),
                    console.log(formData.email),
                    console.log('data sudah terkirim');

                // Send data to server
                fetch(`/users/message/${selectedUserId}`, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
                                .getAttribute('content')
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        if (!response.ok) {
                            return response.json().then(errorData => {
                                throw new Error(errorData.error);
                            });
                        }
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(data => {
                        // Handle successful response
                        console.log('Success:', data);
                        // Hide the form
                        userForm.style.display = 'none';
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
                    });
            } else {
                alert('Please fill out all fields.');
            }
        });

        let userData = localStorage.getItem('chatFormData');
        if (userData) {
            console.log("User data found in local storage:", userData);
            let parsedData = JSON.parse(userData);
            Livewire.dispatch('formDataSubmitted', parsedData);
        } else {
            console.log("No user data found in local storage.");
        }
    });

and its my controller
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Conversation;
use App\Models\Message;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Notifications\MessageSent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Livewire\Component;

class FloatingChat extends Component
{
    public $selectedConversation;
    public $selectedConversationId;
    public $body;
    public $loadedMessages;
    public $paginate_var = 10;
    public $messagesLoaded = false;
    public $showUserForm = true;
    protected $listeners = ['loadMore', 'formDataSubmitted'];
    protected $persist = ['showUserForm'];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->loadedMessages = collect();
    }

    public function loadMore(): void
    {
        $this->paginate_var += 10;
        $this->loadMessages();
        $this->dispatch('update-chat-height');
    }

    public function loadMessages()
    {
        if ($this->selectedConversation) {
            $messagesQuery = Message::where('conversation_id', $this->selectedConversation->id)->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereNull('sender_deleted_at')->orWhereNull('receiver_deleted_at');
            });

            $messagesCount = $messagesQuery->count();
            $messagesToLoad = $messagesQuery
                ->skip(max(0, $messagesCount - $this->paginate_var))
                ->take($this->paginate_var)
                ->get();

            $this->loadedMessages = $messagesToLoad->merge($this->loadedMessages);
        }
    }

    public function sendMessage()
    {
        dd($this->showUserForm);
        $this->validate(['body' => 'required|string']);

        if ($this->selectedConversation) {
            $createdMessage = Message::create([
                'conversation_id' => $this->selectedConversation->id,
                'sender_id' => null, // No login, hence no sender_id
                'receiver_id' => $this->selectedConversation->getReceiver()->id,
                'body' => $this->body,
            ]);

            $this->reset('body');
            $this->dispatch('scroll-bottom');
            $this->loadedMessages->push($createdMessage);
            $this->selectedConversation->updated_at = now();
            $this->selectedConversation->save();

            $this->selectedConversation->getReceiver()->notify(new  MessageSent(null, $createdMessage, $this->selectedConversation, $this->selectedConversation->getReceiver()->id));

            $this->dispatch('newMessage', $createdMessage);
        }
    }

    public function formDataSubmitted($formData, $selectedUserId = null)
    {
        dd($formData['email']);
        $this->validate([
            'formData.name' => 'required|string',
            'formData.email' => 'required|email',
            'formData.phone' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $name = $formData['name'];
        $email = $formData['email'];
        $phone = $formData['phone'];

        Log::info('Form Data:', $formData);
        Log::info('Selected User ID:', $selectedUserId);

        $existingConversation = Conversation::where('email_sender', $email)->first();

        if ($existingConversation) {
            $this->showUserForm = false;
            $this->selectedConversation = $existingConversation;
            $this->selectedConversationId = $this->selectedConversation->id;
        } else {
            $newConversation = Conversation::create([
                'email_sender' => $email,
                'name_sender' => $name,
                'phone_sender' => $phone,
                'admin_id' => $selectedUserId,
            ]);
            $this->selectedConversation = $newConversation;
            $this->selectedConversationId = $newConversation->id;
            $this->showUserForm = false;
        }

        $this->loadMessages();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.floating-chat', [
            'users' => User::where('role', 'admin')->get(),
            'loadedMessages' => $this->loadedMessages,
        ]);
    }
}


In Livewire 3 the dispatch() method must explicitly specify parameter names, frontend side using an object.
In your case the first dispatch from Javascript should be:
Livewire.dispatch("formDataSubmitted", {formData: formData, selectedUserId: selectedUserId});

Here and here you can find the related documentation

The same pattern must be used on the backend side, using named arguments, here the related documentation
